# Minimizing Road Disturbance in Orthophotos for Road Survey using Agisoft Python API

Tags: python-3.x, geolocation, gis, survival-analysis

I've successfully generated orthophoto maps for a road survey project using the Agisoft Python API. However, I've noticed that some areas of the road in the orthophotos appear to be disturbed or unclear. I'm looking for guidance on how to minimize road disturbance and improve the overall clarity of the road features in these orthophotos.

Specifically, I'd like to understand any techniques, settings, or adjustments that can be applied using the Agisoft Python API to achieve the following:

> Reduce or eliminate disturbances in the orthophotos, especially on the road surface.
> Enhance the visibility and detail of road features in the orthophotos.
> Ensure that the orthophotos accurately represent the road conditions as observed during the survey.
> If you have experience in addressing road disturbance issues in orthophotos generated with the Agisoft Python API or similar tools, I would greatly appreciate your insights and recommendations. Any tips or best practices you can provide would be invaluable to my project.